# iOS 10.3 - How to respond to App Store reviews?

Tags: app-store, ios10.3

Now that iOS 10.3 is out, how do us developers go about responding to reviews on our apps. I've tried iTunes Connect, the App Store on Mac and iOS, as well as the Connect iOS app. I'm logged into my developer account on all devices/apps and still don't see the option to respond.

For posterity, this question was asked prior to the feature actually being available for developers via iTunes Connect. They releases 10.3 a few hours before they updated iTunes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an Apple Support question, not a question about programming as defined by the Help Center.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to your iTunes Connect and select the **Activity** tab at the top of the page. Click **Ratings and Reviews** in the sidebar to the left. You'll see all reviews along with an option to reply to each one.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr3er.png)

Notice also the addition of the `Report a Concern` option.

EDIT: Apple now has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ImprovingCustomersExperience.html) available.

Comment: Thank you - it looks like that option was added some time after 10.3 was released.

Answer (score 3):

Login in iTunes Connect > Click My Apps on the homepage > Select your app > Click Activity in the toolbar > Click Ratings and Reviews under the platform in the left column > Click Reply next to the customer review on the ratings and reviews page.

If the Reply option doesn’t appear, you may not have the Legal, Admin, App Manager, or Marketer role.

If you have responded to customer reviews, you can even edit and delete your responses.
Login in iTunes Connect > Click My Apps on the homepage > Select your app > Click Activity in the toolbar > Click Ratings and Reviews under the platform in the left column > Find the review and response you want to edit or delete > Click Edit Response which is next to the review > Edit or delete the response and click Save.

Answer (score -1):

iTunesConnect-App-Activity-Reviews- in the right of each comment - "answer" button

see [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ImprovingCustomersExperience.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH27-SW1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15664370)

Comment: In general, the answer is written in the text, the link is only for those who do not like to read